# Calculate distance between points in differents sketches SolidWorks API

Tags: api, distance, solidworks

I have been working on a script for the application SolidWorks since about a month and a half and I would like to make it better since it is pretty slow.

What my script does : 
1. It tell the user to select some specific component (using advanced Select).
2. I make a collection out of those components.
3. I make a collection out of those collection because I need them regroup depending of their configuration.
4. In every component is a sketch with a single sketchPoint. I have to calculate the distance between this point and the origin of a predetermine point in a 3D sketch. So I bring the sketchPoint attach to my component into my 3Dsketch, I calculate, then I delete it.
5. I Do this for every component (60++)

The time consuming part is the one where I have to Edit my 3DSketch, bring one point into it, Close the edition, calculate the distance, Edit, delete, close again.

I am currently doing a more oriented object approach so no more collection of collection, but still my problem stay. I was wondering if the IMath could be useful since I've seen this : http://help.solidworks.com/2014/english/api/sldworksapi/Transform_Sketch_to_Model_Example_VB.htm 
but it does seems to work properly.

Ah and I am aware of the measure tool but it won't work since I need the negative value if my sketchPoint is "behind" my origin.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have asked the same question on the SolidWorks forum and some one gave me the answer, here it is :

```
Dim myComp As Component2
Dim fSketch As Feature
Dim swSketch As Sketch
Dim vSketchPts As Variant
Dim swSketchPt As SketchPoint
Dim p(2) as Double
Dim mPt as MathPoint
Dim vPt as Variant
Dim myUtil as Mathutility

Set myUtil = swApp.GetMathUtility
Set fSketch = myComp.FeatureByName("mySketchName")
Set swSketch = fSketch.GetSpecificFeature2
vSketchPts = swSketch.GetSketchPoints2
Set swSketchPt = vSketchPts(0)

p(0)=swSketchPt.X
p(1)=swSketchPt.Y
p(2)=0.0
vPt = p
Set mPt = myUtil.CreatePoint(vPt)


Dim mthTrans As MathTransform

Set mthTrans = swSketch.ModelToSketchTransform
Set mPt= mPt.MultiplyTransform(mthTrans.Inverse)
Set mthTrans = swIRBoxComp.Transform2
Set mPt= mPt.MultiplyTransform(mthTrans)
vPt = mPt.ArrayData ' This will contain the XYZ coordinates of the point in the coordinate system of the 3D sketch
```

All credits go to Simon Turner https://forum.solidworks.com/people/1-KQHM1

Comment: If this code works for you then please check this answer :)